# Retain only specified content in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have data in the following form in a file:

```
 <string1>   abc:string2    <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wikicategory_Sports_clubs_established</text\u003e\n______<sha1\u003eqwjfowt5my8t6yuszdb88k2ehskjuh0</sha1\u003e\n____</revision\u003e\n__</page\u003e\n__<page\u003e\n____<title\u003ePortal:Tropical_cyclones/Anniversaries/August_22</title\u003e\n____<ns\u003e100</ns\u003e\n____<id\u003e7957689</id\u003e\n____<revision\u003e\n______<id\u003e446349886</id\u003e\n______<timestamp\u003e2011-08-23T17:38:19Z</timestamp\u003e\n______<contributor\u003e\n________<username\u003eLightbot</username\u003e\n________<id\u003e7178666</id\u003e\n______</contributor\u003e\n______<comment\u003eDelink_non-obscure_units._Conversions._Report_bugs_to_[[User_talk:Lightmouse>.
```

The delimiter in the above file is a tab (`\t`) i.e. `string1` is separated from `abc:string2`by `\t`. Similarly for the rest of the strings.

Now I want to retain just alphabets, numbers, `/`, `:`,'.' and `_` within the strings which are enclosed within `<>`.  I want to delete all the characters apart from the specified ones from the strings which are enlosed in `<>`.

Is there some way by which I may achieve this using linux commands or python? I want to replace all the unwanted characters by an underscore.

```
 <string1>   abc:string2    <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wikicategory_Sports_clubs_established_text_u003e_n_______sha1_u003eqwjfowt5my8t6yuszdb88k2ehskjuh0_sha1_u003e_n_____revision_u003e_n___/page_u003e_n___page_u003e_n_____title_u003ePortal:Tropical_cyclones/Anniversaries/August_22_/title_u003e_n_____ns_u003e100_/ns_u003e_n_____id_u003e7957689_/id_u003e_n_____revision_u003e_n_______id_u003e446349886_/id_u003e_n_______timestamp_u003e2011-08-23T17:38:19Z_/timestamp_u003e_n_______contributor_u003e_n_________username_u003eLightbot_/username_u003e_n_________id_u003e7178666_/id_u003e_n_______/contributor_u003e_n_______comment_u003eDelink_non-obscure_units._Conversions._Report_bugs_to___User_talk:Lightmouse>.
```

Is there some way by which I may achieve this?

Comment: It would be better to stick either to sed or to python in your question, since these are two tools with very different domains of application. Or what you mean is "from the command line", in a Linux one liner? In that case, why not perl also?

Comment: I have removed 'sed' from the question.  I mean to say is there some way in python or linux to achieve the same. Even if its not a one-liner it does not matter me.

Comment: Wouldn't a 'sed' substitution work by using a negated bracket expression in the [regex](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex)?

Comment: i dont know..can u please explain with an example

Comment: Are the only modifications desired between the last `<` and `>`?  I.e., after the second tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieve this just with UNIX tools and some crazy regular expression, but I would write a small Python script for this:

- Open two files (input and output) with `open()`
- Iterate over the input file line by line: `for line in input_file:`
- Split the line at tab: `for part in line.split('\t'):`
- Check if a part is enclosed in `<>`: `if part.startswith('<') and line.endswith('>'):`
- Filter characters with a regular expression: `filtered_part = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9/:._]', '', part)`
- Join the filtered parts back together: `filtered_line = '\t'.join(filtered_parts)`
- Write the filtered line to the output file: `output_file.write(filtered_line + '\n')`

Following this outline, it should be easy for you to write a working script.